# clicksend-java-client giving java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Options with Spring Boot 2.7.0

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to migrate spring boot version from 2.1.7 to  2.7.0
Following dependency is giving an error:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.clicksend</groupId>
        <artifactId>clicksend-java-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
SpringApplication - Application run failed MULTIEXCEPTION org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'okHttpClientBuilder' defined in class 
path resource[org/springframework/cloud/commons/httpclient/HttpClientConfiguration$OkHttpClientConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
    Failed to instantiate [okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder]: 
    Factory method 'okHttpClientBuilder' threw exception; 
    nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: okio/Options
```

How to fix this issue ?